# Discord.js check if bot, loop mention

Tags: javascript, discord.js

So I have this command and it works great, but I'm trying to get it to only pick up users as it also picks up and mentions bots. The idea of the command is to randomly pick people that are users and then `mention` them in a message.

```js
let number = args[0];

if(isNaN(number)){
 return message.channel.send(`Amount isnt a number or no amount listed. !randommention (number)`);
}else{

let ret = "";


for (i = 0; i < number; i++) {
    let randomName = message.guild.members.cache.random().user;
    //Failed attempt to block bots from mention
    if(randomName == message.member.user.bot){
      repeat(randomName)}
    ret += `\n${randomName}`
  }
  

  message.channel.send(`**User(s) Selected:** ${ret}`)

}}
```

I tried a little repeat as a work around which didn't work anyway, but I'm having problems finding how to just avoid anything bot entirely.
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Trust me `while` loops are sometimes useful.
In your case try this

```js
let i = 0;
while(i < number){
    let randomMember = message.guild.members.cache.random();
    //You don't need the .user
    if(randomMember.bot){  //Checks if the user is bot
        continue;
        //Note: if it's a bot the count won't increase
        //So the total count will be equal to the one you want
        //It'll be on a forever loop if there are less members in the guild than selected
    } else { //better be safe
        i ++; //It'll go forward if the user isn't a bot
        ret += `\n${randomMember}`;
    }
}
message.channel.send(`**User(s) Selected:** ${ret}`);
```

Comment: Thanks for the while loop knowledge although I'm still having problems with the bot's getting pinged. I do defiantly like the layout possible with while loop

Comment: Wait I figured a better way. I'll edit the code @ViridoanZe

Comment: wow your code looks amazing it seems the discord api doesn't want to work with me right now and refuses to still bot check lmao